# MJPEG stream in C# from byte[]

Tags: arrays, stream, mjpeg

I have a CCTV camera which produces a stream of raw images which are passed to my application as byte[] when a new frame is received. I'd like to produce an MJPEG stream from these frames so essentially adding a HTTP server to my code.

I've Googled and found various examples of loading a single JPEG into a page but I'm struggling with the concept of sending a continuous feed of images to an already open server.

Can someone point me in the direction of a HTTP server library that may support this or the best functions in code to achieve the end result so I can do some more research and work this out?

Answer (score 0):

In c# it will be something like that:

```
new HttpClient().GetStreamAsync( CAMERA_URL ).CopyToAsync( context.Response.Body )
```

To show MJPEG on web page prety straitforward.
Use IMG html tag and set attribute SRC to point to you camera URL.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp